# Cursor no va después de mi variable y el código no funciona en C#

Tags: c#

Estoy empezando C #. Estoy tratando de programar un recibo simple para incluir el precio de una manzana, naranja y sandía y luego encontrar el subtotal, el impuesto y el total. No puedo entender por qué mi cursor va a la siguiente línea cuando escribo los precios y luego el código deja de funcionar por completo.

```
{
        decimal apple; //first value to add
        decimal orange; //second value to add
        decimal watermelon; //third value to add
        decimal subtotal;
        decimal tax;
        decimal total;


        Console.WriteLine("Receipt for Knight Grocery Store");
        Console.WriteLine("===========================================================");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.Write("                           Apple:         $");
        apple = Convert.ToDecimal( Console.ReadLine() );
        Console.Write("                           Orange:        $");
        orange = Convert.ToDecimal( Console.ReadLine() );
        Console.Write("                           Watermelon:    $");
        watermelon = Convert.ToDecimal( Console.ReadLine() );

        Console.WriteLine("==============================================================");

        subtotal = apple + orange + watermelon; //add values
        tax = subtotal * (0.065m);
        total = subtotal + tax;

        Console.WriteLine("                           Subtotal:      ${0}",
           String.Format("{0:0.00}, subtotal));
        Console.WriteLine("                                Tax:      ${0}",
           String.Format("{0:0.00}, tax));
        Console.WriteLine("                              Total:      ${0}",
            String.Format("{0:0.00}, total));
}
```

Comment: A lo mejor te estas equivocando al ingresar los datos por teclado cuando te pide el precio de cada ítem, como es un decimal debe llevar un punto o una coma dependiendo de tu configuración regional. Intenta ingresando 7.00 o 7,00 y lo sabrás

Comment: Porque los comentarios los pones en ingles?perdona sé que eso no te ayuda, solo tengo curiosidad.

Comment: @Osubarudo son solo buenas practicas de programación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal para cada precio puedes validar tu entrada:

```
private static double LeerPrecio(string title)
{
    while (true) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(title);

        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        double result;


        if (double.TryParse(userInput, 
                            NumberStyles.Any, 
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            out result))
        {
            return result;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Debe escribir un precio, ejemplo: 5, 5.0.");  
    }
}

/// de tu solicitud solo cambias

 manzana= LeerPrecio("Escriba el costo de la manzana por kilo:");

//aqui los demas productos.
```